# INNER JOIN takes too long, each query doesn't

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not an expert in SQL and have to optimize a query that executes very often and causes problems for being too slow.

The `INNER JOIN` is too slow, but the same queries in each table are very fast. How can I optimize the query?

**Table structure:**
`user` has many `threads`, each `thread` has many `messages`. The `messages` table **has a couple of million rows**.

**What I need** is to count the messages of the threads owned by a specific user and sent between two dates.

The inner join takes too long, but doing some testing I found the queries without the join are quite fast:

```sql
/* duration: 3.410, very slow! */
SELECT
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    `message` 
INNER JOIN 
    `thread` ON ( `message`.`thread_id` = `thread`.`id` ) 
WHERE
    (`message`.`sent_date` BETWEEN '2017-04-01 06:02:00' AND '2017-04-28 01:11:02' AND `thread`.`user_id` = 32);

/* duration: 0.157, fast */
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    `message` 
WHERE 
    (`message`.`sent_date` BETWEEN '2017-04-01 06:02:00' AND '2017-04-28 01:11:02' );

/* duration: 0.077, faster */
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    `thread` 
WHERE 
    (`thread`.`user_id` = 32);
```

The `sent_date` fields are indexed, the same as each `fk`

Comment: but you still have to use the index

Answer (score 0):

Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to find the trouble. Use indexes and keys in your query to find rows with specific column values quickly (see [how to use index forced](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) for details).